# Is there a totally ordered set we can map any other totally ordered set to?

Tags: order-theory

Are there any totally ordered sets $O$ with $|O|\ge|\mathbb N|$ such that for each totally ordered set $S$ with $|S|\le|O|$ there is function $f_S\colon S\mapsto O$ such that $\forall_{x,y\in S}x\le y\leftrightarrow f_S(x)\le f_S(y)$?

Comment: For $|O|=|\mathbb N|$ we can take $O=\mathbb Q$. Not in general. Yes, under special assumptions (such as $\mathsf{GCH}$). The point is that we can build *sufficiently saturated* linear orders (these are called $\eta$-sets in the literature), but we need some cardinal arithmetic to ensure they have the right size. A decent reference is Rosenstein's **Linear orderings**.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Thank you. I'll see if my university's library has that.

Comment: Copies seem to be as rare as hen's teeth. I hope someone is nudging Dover to reprint it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm posting this as an answer because it's too long for a comment,
but I'm out of my depth here:)

It seems from $\S6$ of Normal J. Alling's
*Conway's field of surreal numbers*, Trans. AMS **287**,
no. 1 (1985) that for every ordinal $\alpha$,
if $\omega_{\alpha + 1}$ denotes the least ordinal of power
$\aleph_{\alpha + 1}$, and
$$
S_{\alpha + 1} = \{f \in \{0, 1\}^{\omega_{\alpha + 1}}:
\exists \beta < \omega_{\alpha + 1} \text{ s.t. } f(\beta) = 1,
f(\gamma) = 0 \text{ if } \beta < \gamma < \omega_{\alpha + 1} \},
$$
then any totally ordered set of power at most $\aleph_{\alpha + 1}$
has an order-preserving map into $S_{\alpha + 1}$. By $\S4$, under
GCH, $S_{\alpha + 1}$ may be replaced by a set of power
$\aleph_{\alpha + 1}$, which would answer your question.

(I see the question has been edited. The condition was originally $\left\lvert{O}\right\rvert > \left\lvert\mathbb{N}\right\rvert = \aleph_0$.)

Comment: I edited the question because I thought that the case $|O|=|\mathbb N|$ might be interesting, too. Thank you for researching this!